# Add a variable in "load"

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

How would I write this if current was a variable:

```
$('body').load('current body');
```

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply :

```
$('body').load(yourVar + ' body');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation.

```
$('body').load('' + current + ' body');
```